# Combine 2 NSArrays of NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
Array1{ ( Name:david; Place:UK; Work:Google; url:"www.google.com"; id=1;,

Name:John; Place:UK; Work:Yahoo; url:"www.yahoo.com"; id=2;,

Name:david; Place:US; Work:stack; url:"www.facebook.com"; id=3; )}

Array2{ ( Name:david; D.O.B:26.4.2012; url:"www.google.com";

)}
```

There 2 arrays of dictionaries (`Array1` and `Array2`). I want to check both these arrays for common first names (Eg: `David`). But since there are 2 people with the same name in `Array1`, I want to give a second condition for also be compared for both the arrays. If the condition is met, they should be combined into 1 array as showed below (D.o.B is added to only 1st david in array 1)

```
Combined Array{ ( Name:david; Place:UK; Work:Google; url:"www.google.com"; D.O.B:26.4.2012; id=1;,

Name:John; Place:UK; Work:Yahoo; url:"www.yahoo.com"; id=2;,

Name:david; Place:US; Work:stack; url:"www.facebook.com"; id=3;, )}
```

Comment: I see a lot of syntax errors. Let me confirm. `Array1 = @[Dictionary1, Dictionary2, Dictionary3]` and `Array2 = @[Dictionary4]` Correct?

Comment: @raurora Yes that is perfect. I want to first check             if(names are equal){                                            if(url is Equal)                                                 (New combined array}}